# Swift SwiftUI - LazyVStack AVPlayer set the max number of videos that should be cached or set max cache size

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, avplayer

I got in each LazyVStack item:

```
var vidUrl: String
let player: AVPlayer

init(vidUrl: String) {
    self.vidUrl = vidUrl
    player = AVPlayer(url: URL(string: vidUrl)!)
}
```

body:

```
VideoPlayer(player: player)
```

I have hundreds of videos, and with that the RAM doesn't stop to fill, I guess it's because AVPlayer doesn't release the cache?

In Android ExoPlayer I can set either max number of videos that should be cached of just the max cache size.

Is that possible with AVPlayer?